# How can I include two data in one series on HIGHCHARTS?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts stacked and group column to make the following graph:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPmou.png)

I haven't been able to get it working, I have the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Types of answer'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'SORT BY: Ages'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['First Test','Second Test','Third Test']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Numero de pacientes'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -150,
                y: -13,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Answer 1',
                data: [variable1, variable7, variable13],
                stack: 'Less than 18',
                data: [variable19, variable25, variable31],
                stack: 'More than 18'
            },{
                name: 'Answer 2',
                data: [variable2, variable8, variable14],
                stack: 'Less than 18',
                data: [variable20, variable26, variable32],
                stack: 'More than 18'
            },{
                name: 'Answer 3',
                data: [variable3, variable9, variable15],
                stack: 'Less than 18',
                data: [variable21, variable27, variable33],
                stack: 'More than 18'
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

I dont want to use another series because I dont want them to appear in the legend, I want the legend to only list

Answer (score 3):

You can link multiple series into one legend item for hiding and showing and what not using the linkedTo property in the series -

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Temperature',
    data: averages,
    zIndex: 1,
    marker: {
        fillColor: 'white',
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    }
}, {
    name: 'Range',
    data: ranges,
    type: 'arearange',
    lineWidth: 0,
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    zIndex: 0
}]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and the chart the questioner requested can be created with the "linkedTo"-property. Thanks PW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the stack groups in your series.  You series should look similar to this:

```
series: [ {
            name: 'Answer 1',
            data: [variable1, variable7, variable13],
            stack: 'Less than 18'
        },
        {
            name: 'Answer 1',
            data: [variable19, variable25, variable31],
            stack: 'More than 18'
        },
        {
            name: 'Answer 2',
            data: [variable2, variable8, variable14],
            stack: 'Less than 18'
        },
        {
            name: 'Answer 2',
            data: [variable20, variable26, variable32],
            stack: 'More than 18'
        },
        {
            name: 'Answer 3',
            data: [variable3, variable9, variable15],
            stack: 'Less than 18'
        },
        {
            name: 'Answer 3',
            data: [variable21, variable27, variable33],
            stack: 'More than 18'
        }
        ]
```

Comment: The thing is that it will duplicate the name of the series in the legend box, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: The duplicate legend can be avoided by using the "linkedTo"-property (on every second series) mentioned by PW Kad

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find example, how to use `legendItemClick` to connect two series into one legend item: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/326/